# Accessing value with object as key in c++

Tags: c++, stl, maps, key

Sir, I'm implementing bicolor graph. [Here is my sample code](https://ideone.com/uLMFD4) but stucked on when i took `std::map<key,val>` key as user defined object i can't implement like

```
graph[bic].setColor("color");
map<node,node>::iterator itt=graph.begin();
node &kkk=itt->second;
cout<<"not work "<<kkk<<endl;
```

as this the key bic (node type) is not found and in map stl [ ] operator create a reference and return it with default value. [Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) But on the other hand

```
map<node,node>::iterator fnd=find(graph.begin(),graph.end(),bic);
if(fnd==graph.end())
    cout<<"not find"<<endl;
else{
    node& ch=fnd->second;
    ch.setColor("yellow");
}
map<node,node>::iterator it=graph.begin();
node &pp=it->second;
cout<<"work "<<pp<<endl;
```

As i inserted first value of map. the next one is lengthy process to check if a key is exist or not. i want something like overload the subscript operator [ ] of map stl to access the value of a key. but this give me an undesired thing. 
how to implement this sir? eg.

```
    node& cpyNode=graph[Node]; // Node is object of node
            or
    graph[Node].setcolor();    // Node is object of node
```

Comment: `std::map` already has that [`operator []`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) as you describe it. What exactly is not working? Can you show an error message?

Comment: Can we see a definition of `node` too please?  Does it have `operator <`?

Comment: yes sir, https://ideone.com/uLMFD4 you can see the defination of node.

Comment: when i call subscript opoerator graph[bic], then the key "bic" not found,but i've inserted it. and it return the reference of it's new element with initializing the default value. I've inserted the value but when i call operator [ ] i can't get the element of key... thats my problem... sir

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `operator<`.

In a `std::map` two keys are considered equivalent (not unique) if neither compares less then the other.

With your current implementation looking like this

```
bool operator < (const node& ver) const{
    return (this->vertex==ver.vertex);
}
```

it will think that a key is less then another if they have the same vertex value, and you will get even stranger results if you try to do `graph[sing]`.

Since `sing.vertex != bic.vectex` the compare will return false for both `bic < sing` and `sing < bic` and the `std::map` will think that they are equal.

Just change your `operator<` to

```
bool operator < (const node& ver) const{
    return vertex < ver.vertex;
}
```

and you will get the result you expected.

Comment: yes sir... thanks a lot... i've very big mistake to implement the operator < ... thanks sir...